# XMP for Describing, Cataloging, and Searching Files and Folders

Tags: metadata

I am seeking a way to tag files and, if possible, folders or groups of files. I also wish to be able to search the files using these tags. With Windows 7 the search and tagging functions are available but the XMP standard is attractive; for the management of a large amount of geospatial data in a variety of formats, requiring storage in a deeply hierarchical structure,  XMP-tagging (either by embedding or through an associated XMP file) may be a good choice going forward.

Wikipedia has a comparison of metadata editors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_metadata_editors

but I have not found a 'XMP metadata search' function in any software.  Does this exist?  Is XMP a viable solution?